# Java, maven ,eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am building my project using maven tool in eclipse.

I want one folder which I am creating in my current local project to get included in all the projects (Package)after building it on jenkins server.

How can I do that .

Comment: Basically you want to understand the idea of having different "components" (or projects when coming from an eclipse perspective) in your build system. Meaning: learn how to build things separately; and how to specify "dependencies" to other build output artifacts. I know this is pretty general; but in the end; we are talking about "concepts" here; and that requires learning; no way around that.

Comment: The question is "what folder"? Perhaps it needs to go in src/main/resources ?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Subversion to have one source of truth and a nexus as a mirror to all of the other maven-projects(A) using in the organization.

Jenkins tests every single minute if something has been committed to the Subversion, if so it checks-out the changes and call the maven goal "clean install". Install make the modifications available to the nexus. Now, when ever any other project in the organization is built, its asks the nexus if there is a different maven-project(A) available and it downloads the project before compile.

We call it scm and continues delivery.